# Two multi-value parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have two multi-value parameters in my SQL: where (PayToTIN IN (@PayToTIN) or PCP_ProvId IN (@PCP_ProvId).  I am trying to drop in multiple values in either or parameters however when I drop in a value in either parameter, SSRS treats the other parameter as ''.  I am also unable to null out the either param because they are multi-value.  Is there a workaround to run multiple values in either one or the other parameter?

```
    Declare @PayToTIN as varchar(max) = '562660402' --'562660402'   
Declare @PCP_ProvId as varchar(max) --= 'LASRL12550' --'LASRL12550'
declare @detailfields as varchar(max) = NULL

declare @PayToTIN_switch varchar(max) =  
    (   select max(PayToTIN)
        from LA_Temp.dbo.vMemberPCP
        where cast(PayToTIN as varchar) in (@PayToTIN)
    )

declare @PCPAssignmentID_switch varchar(max) =  
    (   select max(PCP_ProvId)
        from LA_Temp.dbo.vMemberPCP
        where cast(PCP_ProvId as varchar) in (@PCP_ProvId)
    )

declare @include_PayToTIN bit = case when 'Pay To Tin' in (@detailfields) then 1 else 0 end 
declare @include_PCP_ProvId bit = case when 'PCP ProvID' in (@detailfields) then 1 else 0 end 

select distinct 
    x.CarrierMemID
--  , MemberName
    , MbrLastName =rtrim( e.LastName)
    , MbrFirstName = rtrim(e.FirstName)
    , MbrMI = rtrim(e.MiddleName)
    , x.DOB
    , x.Age
    , x.Sex
    , Address = e.addr1
    , City = e.city
    , State = e.state
    , Zip = e.zip
    , Parish = e.county
    , MemPhone = e.phone
    , PCPName
    , PCP_NPI
    , PCPProvID
    , PCPEffDate
    , Specialty
    , ServiceLocation
    , PayToProvider
    , PayToTIN
    , PayToProvID
    , PCP_ProvId 
    , PCPAssignment
from LA_Temp.dbo.vMemberPCP x
inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.enrollkeys ek
    on x.enrollid = ek.enrollid
inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.orgpolicy o
    on o.orgpolicyid = ek.orgpolicyid
    and right(rtrim(o.policynum),2) <> 'BH'
inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.member m
    on ek.memid = m.memid
inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.entity e
    on e.entid = m.entityid
--where  PayToTIN = @PayToTIN --AMB 05/07/18
where  (PayToTIN IN (@PayToTIN) 
                        or '' = @PayToTIN_switch
                )
        or (    PCP_ProvId IN (@PCP_ProvId)
                or '' = @PCPAssignmentID_switch
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where (case when PayToTIN = '' then null else PayToTIN end in (@PayToTIN)) 
OR (case when PCP_ProvId = '' then null else PCP_ProvId end in (@PCP_ProvId))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.